# root permission denied on /proc/1/exe

Tags: linux, permissions, process, proc, lsof

I just performed a fresh ubuntu install and i am seeing the following in lsof:

```
userA@az1:~$ lsof
COMMAND    PID  TID       USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
init         1            root  cwd   unknown                          /proc/1/cwd  (readlink: Permission denied)
init         1            root  rtd   unknown                          /proc/1/root (readlink: Permission denied)
init         1            root  txt   unknown                          /proc/1/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
init         1            root NOFD                                    /proc/1/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
kthreadd     2            root  cwd   unknown                          /proc/2/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
kthreadd     2            root  rtd   unknown                          /proc/2/root (readlink: Permission denied)
kthreadd     2            root  txt   unknown                          /proc/2/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
kthreadd     2            root NOFD                                    /proc/2/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
```

Is this normal? If not how do I fix it? Trying to search for this particular error has lead me nowhere.

I am concerned that something is wrong because root is getting `Permission denied` errors.

ls -la result for the proc folder:
`dr-xr-xr-x 145 root root     0 Jan 13 17:33 proc`

ls -la results for contents are:
`dr-xr-xr-x   9 root       root                     0 Jan 13 17:34 1`

and for the contents of process 1.

```
sudo ls -la /proc/1/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root 0 Jan 13 17:34 .
dr-xr-xr-x 145 root root 0 Jan 13 17:33 ..
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 attr
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 autogroup
-r--------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 auxv
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:34 cgroup
--w-------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 clear_refs
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:34 cmdline
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 comm
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 coredump_filter
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 cwd
-r--------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 environ
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:34 exe
dr-x------   2 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 fd
dr-x------   2 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 fdinfo
-r--------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 io
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 latency
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 limits
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 loginuid
dr-x------   2 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 map_files
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 maps
-rw-------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 mem
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 mountinfo
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 mounts
-r--------   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 mountstats
dr-xr-xr-x   5 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 net
dr-x--x--x   2 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 ns
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 numa_maps
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 oom_adj
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 oom_score
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 oom_score_adj
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 pagemap
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 personality
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 root
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 sched
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 schedstat
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 sessionid
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 smaps
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 stack
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 stat
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 statm
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 status
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 syscall
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root root 0 Jan 13 17:35 task
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 timers
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Jan 13 17:42 wchan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you did not run `lsof` as root, given that you show a prompt with `$`. Run `sudo lsof` to execute the `lsof` command as root.

Some information about a process, such as its current directory (`pwd`), its root directory (`root`), the location of its executable (`exe`) and its file descriptors (`fd`) can only be viewed by the user running the process (or root). That's normal behavior. Sometimes the permission to access files in `/proc` doesn't match the permission in the directory entries, it's finer-grained (for example, it depends on processes' effective UID as well as real UID).

You might get “permission denied” as root in some unusual circumstances, when you're root only in a namespace. If you just installed a new machine, you won't be seeing this.